# Generate an aperiodic integer sequence

Tags: code-golf, math

Your task is to build a piece of code that generates an aperiodic sequence of integers, either by outputting one every time it iterates, or by taking an integer `n` and returning the `n`th number in that sequence.

Now, the sequence `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, ...` is itself aperiodic, so I'm going to introduce a few limitations to the definition of "aperiodic" used in this problem to weed out the trivial cases:

- The sequence must not be periodic modulo any integer `m > 1`. So a sequence like the powers of 2 would repeat `2, 4, 8, 6` all the time modulo 10, and therefore not count. (It would also repeat `0` modulo 2.)
- The sequence must not become periodic after a certain number of operations - e.g. `1 2 4 8 6 2 4 8 6 ...` is still considered periodic even though 1 never appears again.
- The generation code must only use integers. So a piece of code that calculated the `n`th digit of pi (without calculating it in some integer form first) would not be acceptable.

Now, obviously every sequence performed with limited computer memory will eventually either be periodic or run out of memory, but if you can prove that your function, given infinite memory and time, will never loop back to a previous state, then it is acceptable.

The shortest code that does the above wins.

Comment: What about strings? Can we use strings or arrays of numbers?

Comment: I assume we cannot use randomness lest it would be too easy?

Comment: @JanDvorak: Yes, you can use strings, but they will factor into your code length.

Comment: And you can use randomness, but it will take too much code if you want it to be aperiodic.

Comment: Btw you can calculate the nth digit of pi using only integers.

Comment: @Howard: If you can produce to code to do that, it will be acceptable. What I meant is a code that calculates pi and then multiplies it by whatever power of 10.

Comment: I doubt anyone can beat my 2-character golfscript solution. Anyone fluent in APL?

Comment: Do rules 1 and 2 combine to prohibit sequences which become periodic modulo `m`? I think it matters for such a simple sequence as `n!`

Comment: @PeterTaylor good note - I interpreted that that they do. If not, there's a trivial one-character solution in golfscript and J

Comment: @JanDvorak [Burlesque](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Burlesque) - 2 bytes: `gl`. Does the same thing as your GolfScript solution.

Comment: @Peter Taylor: Yes. Those rules apply together.

Comment: You might be interested in my work on BiEntropy, which evaluates the order and disorder of a finite binary sequence. The sequence 1,2,3,4,5,6... is in fact periodic (ie the first differences 0,0,0,0,0....of the sequence are perfectly periodic). http://arxiv.org/abs/1305.0954 The paper includes an evaluation of the disorder of the prime number sequence and the digits of pi and e etc.

Comment: @JanDvorak: in APL, if you want a function the best you can do is 3, I think: `⍴∘⍕` (length of string representation) or `⌊∘⍟` (floor of log-e). A (slightly cheaty) full expression could get down to 2: `⍴⍞`, which reads a line from the keyboard and then tells you how long it is, so if you tell the user to only type numbers it'd work.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## Golfscript, 2 characters

```
`,
```

(stringify (`` ` ``) the number and count (`,`) the digits)

## J, 3 characters

```
#q:
```

is the count (`#`) of the prime factors (`q:`) of its input.

The vector form involves more bookkeeping, but that's not our contestant:

```
#@q:L:0&.<
```

the first 40 terms are: 0 1 1 2 1 2 1 3 2 2 1 3 1 2 2 4 1 3 1 3 2 2 1 4 2 2 3 3 1 3 1 5 2 2 2 4 1 2 2 4

[see more at OEIS](http://oeis.org/A001222)

The sequence is 1 at every prime position, 2 at every prime multiple of a prime, 3 at every prime multiple of a product of two primes...

---

If you are not convinced this is aperiodic, here are plenty of other sequences:

```
##:
```

(the number of bits = floor of the base-2 logarithm)

```
+/#:
```

(count of 1-bits in the binary representation of the number). This (reduced under any modulus)

```
#b#:
+/b#:
```

(the same in base-b)

```
<.^.
>.^.
<.b^.
>.b^.
```

(floor or ceiling of the (natural) log - this time without stringification)

```
*./#:
+./b#:
*./b#:
```

(GCD or LCM of all base-b digits (except GCD of bits won't work))

```
1{#:!
9{#:!
({#:@!)
```

(second/tenth/nth highest bit of the factorial of n)

```
(=<.&.%:)
```

(Is the number equal its floor under the square root operation? Is the number equal the square of the floor of its square root? Is the number a square?)

Comment: I don't think anybody here needs convincing that the pattern of primes is aperiodic.

Comment: @breadbox the pattern of primes is aperiodic, but what about the pattern of numbers that have an odd number of prime power divisors?

Comment: For the J part of the solution, why not just use `p:` (the nth prime)? After all, you said yourself that the pattern of primes is aperiodic.

Comment: @Volatility the sequence of primes is periodic modulo 2 as all primes are odd. If rules 1+2 are not meant to be taken together, then a simple factorial will do (as noted by Peter Taylor). `-:<:p:` would likely be a valid sequence, but it's a bit longer.

Comment: Ah, missed that, sorry.

Comment: If rules 1 and 2 aren't taken together then the primes do work, because the first one is even. Even if they are, the prime indicator function works, although that seems to be 4 characters in J: [1 p:](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/dpco.htm).

Comment: @PeterTaylor nice one, too

Answer (score 4):

## Python, <s>48</s> 25 bytes

Volatility's version, using string operations:

```
f=lambda a:int(`2**a`[0])
```

Numerical version (48 bytes):

```
def f(a):
 m=2**a
 while m>9:
  m/=10
 return m
```

Sequence it returns (first 100 terms):

```
1 2 4 8 1 3 6 1 2 5 1 2 4 8 1 3 6 1 2 5 1 2 4 8 1 3 6 1 2 5 1 2 4 8 1 3 6 1 2 5
1 2 4 8 1 3 7 1 2 5 1 2 4 9 1 3 7 1 2 5 1 2 4 9 1 3 7 1 2 5 1 2 4 9 1 3 7 1 3 6
1 2 4 9 1 3 7 1 3 6 1 2 4 9 1 3 7 1 3 6
```

This returns the first digit of the `a`th power of 2, which is aperiodic because log<sub>10</sub> 2 is irrational, and no multiple of it besides 0 will be an integer. (So while it may *look* periodic for a long time, eventually there will always be something to break the period.)

I could probably golf for whitespace, but I'm not experienced with that.

Comment: Why not just `f=lambda a:int(\`2**a\`[0])`?

Comment: @Volatility Good question. I didn't think of using string operations.

Comment: Why do people assign their lambdas to variables?

Comment: @CatsAreFluffy Unnamed lambdas weren't always allowed.

Answer (score 4):

## Python, 14

```python
int.bit_length
```

This generates the following sequence:

```python
>>> f=int.bit_length
>>> [f(i) for i in range(20)]
[0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5]
```

Comment: `lambda x:\`x\`[0]`

Answer (score 3):

## Perl -p, 7 characters

```
$_.=/1/
```

Takes an integer n on the standard input and outputs the nth number in the following sequence:

```
11 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 101 111 121 131 141 151 161 171 181 191 20 211 22 23 24 25 26...
```

Answer (score 2):

### Sage, 7

[Sage](http://www.sagemath.org/help.html%20Sage) has the integer-part-of-the-square-root function built-in :

```
f=isqrt

[f(n) for n in [0..20]]
->  [0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]
```

A number of [OEIS](http://oeis.org/) sequences are also Sage built-ins named using the OEIS index, and would score a length of **16**; e.g.,

```
f=sloane.A000120

f;[f(n) for n in [0..20]
->  1's-counting sequence: number of 1's in binary expansion of n.
    [0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 4, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

### Perl, <s>19</s> 18 characters

Simplicity itself:

```
sub f{"@_"=~/(.)/}
```

Given an integer `n`, the function `f` returns the `n`th number in the sequence.

For those not conversant in Perl, `f` returns the leading decimal digit in `n`. As the sequence continues, you get progressively longer runs of the current number. Thus the sequence is transparently aperiodic, and avoids devolving into any of the trivial cases listed above.

Comment: +1 for simplicity. `$_[0]` may be replaced with `"@_"` for one byte.

Answer (score 0):

## [RETURN](https://github.com/molarmanful/RETURN), 9 bytes (noncompetitive)

```
0[' ,1+$¦{\3}§.1!]!
```

<kbd>[Try it here.](http://molarmanful.github.io/RETURN/)</kbd>

Make sure to run using "timed run," because this is an infinite stream. Also replace `\3` with character `U+0003`.

## Explanation

Basically just outputs each number reversed. I couldn't find any periodicity, but please tell me if you do.